# FluentFTP. Вывожу прогресс скачивания файла, но как сделать, чтобы если скачивалось допустим файлов 10 и выводился их совместный прогресс

Tags: c#, ftp, progress-bar

```
Progress<FtpProgress> progress = new Progress<FtpProgress>(x => {

    // When progress in unknown, -1 will be sent
    if (x.Progress < 0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        progressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(x.Progress);
    }
});
```

такой код откопал в документации на гитхабе. Там еще было `progressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;`  но оно у меня не заработало, я удалил и вроде что-то как-то работает. Но мне надо не отдельного файла а всех файлов которые скачиваются и вообще как сделать так, чтобы библиотека сама скачивала поочередно, например если бы я мог ввести в DownloadFile сразу 10 файлов и он их поочередно скачал, или мне придется это самому реализовывать?

Comment: Я не в курсе вашей либы, но мне кажется такое надо самому считать. Вот будут у вас 2 файла, один на 5% скачан, второй на 50% - что вы юзеру покажете? А если первый файл на гигабайт, а второй на мегабайт? 4

Comment: ну например посчитается вес всех файлов, например 1 гб (допустим 3 файла: один 100 мб, второй 300, третий 600) и пользователю будет показываться процесс скачивания этого гигабайта, а не каждого файла по отдельности.

Comment: Можно конечно узнать вес каждого файла, прибавить его, а потом прогресс каждого файла, перевести в мб и вот так и отправить в прогрессбар, но мне кажется это как-то неправильно, есть какой-то умный способ.